# Javascript for loop optimization

Tags: javascript

The classic for loop structure in Javascript is something like this:

```
// original loop
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    process(items[i]);
}
```

But I have recently came across an article about how we can optimize loops in JS ([here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-optimize-your-javascript-apps-using-loops-d5eade9ba89f/)) that gives an intersting optimized reverse version of a foor loop as follows:

```
// minimizing property lookups and reversing
for (var i = items.length; i--; ){
    process(items[i]);
}
```

Suppose that we have an array like let v = ["C", "P", "L", "T"] so when you run the above for loop for this array:

```
for (let i = v.length; i--;) {
console.log(v[i]);}
```

It will log the array items in reverse order. The confusing thing is this version of a for loop doesn't have a pretest condition or it seems so at least so how come that it works nevertheless and how it knows it should stop decrementing i when it reaches 0?

Comment: _"optimised"_ into unreadable code...

Comment: First of all, you don't really need it :) As of why it works:  0 is falsy so as soon as `i--` hits 0 the loop stops.

Comment: `i--` is the pretest condition. It gets evaluated as false when `i` is 0, and `i` is decremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to recognize here is that the *test* to see if the loop should stop executing - the second part of a `for` loop declaration, the `i--` - evaluates to an *expression* which can be tested for truthyness/falseyness:

```js
let i = 2;
console.log(i--);
console.log(i--);
console.log(i--);
```

The `i--` not only decrements the variable in `i`, but it also evaluates to an expression equivalent to `i` before the decrement occurs.

Since the test (the `i--`) is carried out on every iteration, `i` is decremented on every iteration, and it stops once the iteration for `i = 0` finishes.

But this is a *really really* strange thing to want to do. As commenters have noted, it looks exceedingly odd and is hard to read and understand.

Performance is rarely an issue worth worrying about in 99% of code. Better to optimize for code clarity and readability. *If* you later run a performance test and see that a particular part of the code is running too slowly, go ahead and try to fix it - but reversing a `for` loop like this is almost certainly not a bottleneck, so you're just making the code harder to read for no real benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the for is the following:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [finale_expression])
   instruction
```

In your sample, there is no `finale_expression` so the `i--` is both the `condition` and the `finale_expression`. That means the `for` will loop while `i` is true, which is the case while it's greater than 0.